# python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by python3)

Tags: python, virtualenv, glibc

When I use :

```
$ source ./bin/activate
(wink) mohsen@debian:~/m_and_m/wink$ python3
python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by python3)
python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by python3)
python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by python3)
python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by python3)
```

And When :

```
$ deactivate 
mohsen@debian:~/m_and_m/wink$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Indeed it can't load glibc or its path when I use `virtualenv`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: How did you create that virtualenv? Can you try deleting it and creating it again?

Comment: Did you update your global Python version recently, or have multiple python versions installed? Have you tried re-creating a new virtual env?

Comment: `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 .` @Chris

Comment: It's solved. I recreated `virtualenv`

Answer (score 1):

You have to recreate your virtual environment. You can follow the [instructions from pythonanywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RebuildingVirtualenvs/) with some adaptations:

1. If not already done, manually record packages you are using in a `requirements.txt` file. You cannot use `pip freeze` as in the pythonanywhere's instructions because the original virtualenv is broken.
2. Remove your old virtualenv (make a backup before)

   ```
   rm -rf /home/myusername/path/to/virtualenv
   ```
3. Create a new virtualenv

   ```
   virtualenv --python=pythonX.Y /home/myusername/path/to/virtualenv
   ```
4. Reinstall your packages

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

Comment: for step 1, pip freeze will not work if python3 won't even run.

Comment: You are right, you have to do it manually. I've updated my answer.